# Adding .h, .m, .framework and .a file to already built .framework' target's Build Phases

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

Having a `test.framework`. I want to add a .h ,.m ,.framework and .a files after .framework file builds.

What I want to achieve is let user choose these files while downloading my framework:

- `test.framework` **[!]**
- `test123.framework`
- `test234.framework`

**[!]** means required.

Now assumming user has downloaded `test.framework` and included it in his project, my goal is to Internally check in `initSDK()` if user has also downloaded `test123.framework` or `test234.framework` or not when calling `initSDK()` method of downloaded `test.framework` using following code:

```
#if __has_include(<test123/test123.h>)
    NSLog(@"test123 included");
#else
    NSLog(@"test123 not included");
#endif
```

However, I'm always getting `test123 not included`, whether or not including `test123.framework` in project.

Is it possible to include .h ,.m ,.framework and .a files after .framework file build?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different project targets and add the extra files just in target `test123` and `test456`.

[image]

This guide shows you how manage different targets: https://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app

Comment: No, This is not possible, because I have called some methods of `test123.framework` in `test.framework`, after checking if framework is present.